# pdo isn't getting parameter value

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to php and pdo.  I have the following code.

```
$buildFormId = 1;
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from WebsiteBuildForm where id=:id");
$query->bindParam(':id', $buildFormId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();

if ($query->rowCount() == 0){
    echo "found nothing for ".$buildFormId;
    exit;
}
```

In this case I get the message that nothing was found.  However if change the code to this, it works.

```
$buildFormId = 1;
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from WebsiteBuildForm where id=".$buildFormId);
$query->execute();
```

From the examples for pdo that I've seen the first code block "should" work.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Does the PDO query work if you remove `PDO::PARAM_INT`?

Comment: no.  I've also tried it without the bindParam line instead using ? in the query and an array in the execute call.

Comment: your code worked for me, so you've got some typo and this question is not a real one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the fact you can't reproduce doesn't mean there is no problem... It may be specific to his config or something else...

Comment: did you try $query->bindValue() instead of bindParam()?

Comment: yes, I tried both bindParam and bindValue

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should work for one and not the other.

Comment: Found my answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828215/using-typed-bound-parameters-with-php-pdo-odbc-unixodbc-and-freetds Changed the FreeTDS version from 8.0 to 7.2 and parameters work now.

Comment: @geoffswartz Feel free to flag this one as a duplicate of the other one then, or delete it.